# preventing php exec from waiting

Tags: php, ajax, asynchronous, exec

i have been working for a while now to try and get some php code to run asyncronously i have seen various posts.

I want my script to run some extra formatting but return the script quickly and not wait for the exec command response here is my code so far.

```
//convert ogg
exec("cd {$targetDir}/ && ffmpeg -i {$tmpname}.wav -c:a libvorbis out.ogg > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");                              
//convert mp3
exec("cd {$targetDir}/ && ffmpeg -i {$tmpname}.wav out.mp3 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");

return ajax response
```

Can someone tell me if this is even possible and can be done

Comment: Say this is possible: Why would you want it? When calling the script, you wouldn't know if it was successful or not (as you didn't wait for the exec to run properly)

Comment: Hi Barmar because i want it to return the script after a m4a file is uploaded return and then process the other two formats afterwards takes too long waiting for all formats to be converted the ajax request timesout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a different approach:

1. Add the jobs in a database in a job queue;
2. Have a cron job process jobs that have not been processed yet **and** that are not being processed; that script would load the oldest non-processed and not being-processed item from the database, set a "being processed" flag and run the job sychronously;
3. When a job is finished (in the same script as it is synchronously), mark it as processed and sent a mail to the owner.

You could even have a page check that same database to get the status for the user; in queue, processsed and done in the simplest form.

Comment: Hi jeroen do you know any simple tutorials on how to do the above or where to start as the process above just doesnt work for me

Comment: @user1503606 No, I've never really looked for any. You should post detailed questions if you run into problems at any step.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're running several different commands chained together before backgrounding with the `&`.

Stick your whole command in `()` then add the `&`

```
exec("(cd {$targetDir}/ && ffmpeg -i {$tmpname}.wav -c:a libvorbis out.ogg > /dev/null 2>/dev/null ) &");                              
exec("(cd {$targetDir}/ && ffmpeg -i {$tmpname}.wav out.mp3 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null ) &");
```

If you need the return values from the exec, but don't want to wait on it before responding back to the user, you can always stick the execs in a deconstructor of an object... consider that a poor mans job queue :)

Here's an example if you need to do something with the exec results

```
class Foo(){

    public function __destruct(){
        //These exec's won't be backrounded, but this method is only call after the object is
        //  is being garbage collected, so the user's not waiting on the results
        exec("cd {$targetDir}/ && ffmpeg -i {$tmpname}.wav -c:a libvorbis out.ogg > /dev/null 2>/dev/null ");                   
        exec("cd {$targetDir}/ && ffmpeg -i {$tmpname}.wav out.mp3 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null ");

        //exec's are done, now do anything else you want here...
    }

}
```

One caveat with this approach is even if the client has moved on, the process is still running, consuming memory and if using php-fpm it's holding a process.

The 'real' way to do this (process stuff offline)  is a basic job queueing server--a topic far more than can be covered in this post

Comment: Hi Ray could you explain how i would stick the execs in a deconstructor of an object. as this is exactly what i am after i want it too respond to the user i dont need responses from the exec

Comment: @user1503606 if you don't need any response from the exec, just wrap the commands in the parentesis and put a & at the end.  but if you've got an object, just like the __construct() method, there is a __destruct() that gets called when the object is be freed from memory--usually post response.

Comment: ok thanks ray ill see if i can figure that out if not i will just have to settle for 3 ajax calls with callbacks for each file

Comment: @user1503606 I added a brief example of using the destruct method.  You could set up a some kind ajax polling to see if the job is done.